# Gravity dual of the string world-sheet CFT?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, quantum-gravity, ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

The AdS/CFT correspondence conjectures a duality between a $(D+1)$ dimensional gravity theory in asymptotic AdS spacetime with a $D$ dimensional conformal field theory. Is there any sense in asking whether the 2D CFT on the string world-sheet could have a 3D gravity dual? Is it possible that the 2D string world-sheet is dual to a "mini" interior 3D AdS spacetime?

I know this is not what holography experts are referring to when they study $AdS_{3}/CFT_{2}$, and I'm not even sure if my question makes any sense.

Comment: A Wess-Zumino-Witten model with a group $G$ can be seen as a worldsheet CFT for a string living in a manifold of a Lie group. Its holographic dual is a 3d Chern-Simons theory with a gauge group $G$.

Comment: @A.V.S, thank you. I fear I'm confusing concepts, because I'm wondering if this is at all related to Witten's conjecture from the 80s that (2+1)D gravity is dual to a Chern-Simons theory?

Comment: … *gravity is dual to a Chern-Simons* Not “dual” in the sense of holography. Rather there is a rewrite of 3d Einstein-Hilbert gravity with cosmological constant as a 3d CS theory with specific gauge groups (such as $SO(2,2)$). This works classically, but IIRC there are consistency issues in the quantum realm.

Comment: @A.V.S thank you once again. So, it is possible to reformulate the 2D CFT of the world sheet as a 3D theory, not as a 3D metric gravity theory, but rather as a 3D topological field theory (which is at least classically related to the 3D Einstein Hilbert action). Am I stating this correctly?

Comment: Yes. But in 3d metric gravity *is* a topological theory (since it does not have local dof's).

Comment: This could lead somewhere deep, because if an AdS3 dual to the worldsheet CFT does exist, the next question is, what is its relation (if any) to the usual string vacuum defined by that worldsheet theory? E.g. is the "space near the string" governed by the AdS3 theory (which would actually be AdS3 x M7 for some 7-manifold)? I think Lubos Motl expressed this thought once, and you may be reaching for it with your own comment about "mini interior spacetime".

Comment: @MitchellPorter hmmm, interesting... I dunno.
The reason I even asked the question instead of tossing it aside as absurd was because of the non-intuitive implications of string dualities. It might be absurd to think about a "mini-AdS" inside a closed string, but then again, the results of, say, T duality seem similarly absurd. I'm not sure if these dualities point in the direction to answer your question. Then again, if A.V.S is right then I'm on the wrong track looking for a metric space inside the string. Maybe it's purely topological.